# Microsoft Access VBA clicking a button on intranet site

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been stuck on this code for about a week now. I have an access form that when completed will take the user to the reference claim number on our intranet site. While on that site, I would like one more step to be completed which is to go to the file note section where the user can paste their information. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
'Set appIE = Nothing
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "Intranet" & [claim]
With appIE
.Navigate sURL
.Visible = True
End With

While appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Set ele = appIE.Document.getElementById("btnFileNotes_unselected")
ele.Click


Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get an

> Run Time Error: 91

on the `ele.click`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Runtime error 91 "object variable not set" which means that "ele" was not set. First you might add a Dim for ele.  Then in your browser Inspect the field and make sure "btn..." is spelled right.

Comment: Dim ele as object?

Comment: try it, see what happens

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: ok, and what about Inspect to insure correct spelling of "btn..." to ensure no unknown prefix/suffix...

Comment: I just created an mdb with your code, and went to url "Internetwxyz" which comes back "does not exist", and has no "btn..." .  And when I changed the By to "diagnose" which does exist then ele was set.  This points to mis-spelling of "btn..."

Comment: Here is the HTML code.

<A id=btnFileNotes_unselected title="Create File Note - ALT+c" 
class=menuEnabled style="DISPLAY: block" accessKey=c href="../../Desktop/FileNotes/FileNote.aspx?UIC=_NewUOW%3dTrue%26_SecEntityType%3d1%26c_sMode%3d2%26FNLiveDescInd%3dTrue%26_SecEntityId%3d7EB053F1EF3D4BBB%26FileNoteID%3d%26FNCloseWindowOnSave%3dFalse&amp;BID=FB4647BE35287E0E" target=fraMain DirtyMsg="You are about to lose ALL changes!  Press OK to continue"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><IMG border=0 src="../../common/images/btnMenuFileNotes-reg.gif"><U>C</U>reate<BR>File Note</A>